# Numbered sentence

Tags: numbering

In LaTeX, how can I enumerate sentences in text? I have a situation there I have to write something like:

In addition, we might add to the structure the following condition:

(2) If $x$ and $y$ are integers, then ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify your formatting objective(s). E.g., If some condition is numbered `(2)`, are there other conditions numbered `(1)`, `(3)`, etc. elsewhere in the document? Are the conditions part of a theorem, proposition, lemma, etc? Or should one set up a theorem-like environment called, say, `Condition`? Please advise.

Comment: I reading the book "Field arithmetic" from https://www.pdfdrive.com/field-arithmetic-d159923919.html The situation appears on page 146. In the previous page there is the formula (1). I was wondering how this can be done in LaTeX.

Comment: For numbered environments with a label (like Lemma 1, Lemma 2 or Condition 1, Condition 2) see for example https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Theorems_and_proofs. If you don't want a label then you can use equations, but they are intended for purely mathematical content (no text), see for example https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_expressions. If you want non-math content without a label then you can define your own environment, see for example https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Environments#Numbered_environments.

Comment: Maybe you can make use of enumerate in combination with the resume option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want enumeration throughout the document you can use package `linguex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\ex. SOME TEXT AS RULE NO. 1

\lipsum
\ex. SOME TEXT AS RULE NO. 2

\lipsum
\ex. SOME TEXT AS RULE NO. 3

\lipsum
\ex. SOME TEXT AS RULE NO. 4

\end{document}
```

Don't forget to leave a blank line after your item gets over. That is the requirement of the package.

Comment: The OP seems to be more interested in single sentences/items that appear throughout the document with consecutive numbers (sort of a theorem without the word 'Theorem' in front), instead of a list (see his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504299/numbered-sentence#comment1273922_504299)).

Comment: Oh, let me edit then.

Comment: @Marijn Is this the solution now?

Comment: To me, this looks more like what is being asked, yes. But of course the OP is the only one that can fully judge this :) +1 from me.

Comment: This is a package developed by linguists (lazy linguists as the documentation says :P) for writing examples in the text, hence the name is `linguex`. A very nice package.